# Prevent scheduled task from running when an app is running (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, tasks

I have a task scheduled for `robocopy.exe` for backup of some files and SQL database daily at 22.00.

Is there a way to prevent this task from running when an `XYZ.exe` application is running?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly running robocopy, you can run a batch script checking if the process `XYZ.exe` is running.

It should be something like that :

```
REM Check if XYZ.exe is running
tasklist | find "XYZ.exe"

REM exit if the process is running
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 exit

REM otherwise run robocopy command
robocopy XXXX
```